# Scroll Down [GeckoFx + Javascript]

Tags: javascript, c#, c#-4.0, geckofx

I'm trying to scroll down a page with GeckoFx v33 and Javascript.
My C# code is the following:

```
        private void scrollWb() {
        string command = "window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);";
        using (Gecko.AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(wb.Window.JSContext))
        {
            var result = context.EvaluateScript(command, wb.Window.DomWindow);

        }
```

My code doesn't work... Can anyone help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling is handled using the methods of the Window object:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a .ScrollIntoView() property of a GeckoHtmlElement to get to a specific element.