# How to scroll down while page loading - GeckoFx C#

Tags: c#, geckofx

I want to scroll down while a page loading in geckofx 45.
I tried to to do with following code, but it seems not to work.

```
   wb.Navigate("javascript: var s = function() { window.scrollBy(550, 10000); }; s();");
```

How is that possible?

Comment: Alternatively, wihtout using AutoJSContext, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548216/scroll-down-geckofx-javascript/43874101#43874101

Comment: This is also helpful.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 int scrollTo = 30;
    public void scrollDown()
    {
        this.wb.Focus();
        string result = string.Empty;
        AutoJSContext context;
        string jsScript = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (scrollTo > 100)
            {
                scrollTo = 5;
            }

            context = new AutoJSContext(this.wb.Window);
            jsScript = "var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ANY_ELEMENTS_CLASS_NAME');   x[" + (scrollTo * 2) + "].scrollIntoView(); ";// CHANGE ANY_ELEMENTS_CLASS_NAME 

            context.EvaluateScript(jsScript, (nsISupports)wb.Window.DomWindow, out result);
            scrollTo += 5;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

this helped me